# importing an autotools project in eclipse doesn't find all includes, breaks autocomplete

Tags: eclipse, autotools

I have an `autotools` project that **references an external directory** containing **build output** of a different project (headers, libs, etc...).  *configuring* and *building* via command line works fine.  After importing via `eclipse` as an existing autotools project, none of the headers/references in that second project are found by eclipse.

Eclipse also fails to find a few libraries/headers that are in non-standard system locations like `/opt`, etc...  Thus, autocomplete, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>, etc... doesn't work on a lot of things.

Both the second project and the non-standard libraries are correctly referenced when building/compiling and are found properly by configure

I'm able to manually add the necessary paths in the `C/C++` build settings to get all of the includes resolved, but I was under the impression that importing an autotools project should automatically find these references.  Am I incorrect in that assumption?

An additional note, our configure script requires the use of `--prefix` to know where to find the second project.  when importing the project the first time, it of course tries to autoconf everything without `--prefix` set and subsequently fails.  I then go back in and modify eclipse to use the appropriate prefix OR manually **re-run** autogen and configure with `--prefix=/some/path`.  Then **re-index** the project.  so everything should be setup fine at this point.

Comment: Your configure script should not rely on the specified prefix for locating anything.  That is intended to speak only to where the project's own artifacts will be installed.

Comment: that is true, but we have a very complex and odd environment.  --prefix was used when building various components, almost as a hack.  When we're building RPMS, we do not abuse --prefix.    In actuality, --prefix is being used to change where things are installed like normal, but it's also used as a reference to where a group of headers and libraries are located.

regardless of that, should eclipse autotools plugin just "find" everything assuming that I can build and install from command line without error?

Comment: No, @AndrewS, I do not expect Eclipse to discover and integrate library or include paths that are hardcoded into your Autotooling or that have been `configure`d on a build tree.  Among other things, it doesn't need that to build the project, since it relies on the Autotools-based build system for that instead of its own built-in system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual question seems to be this:

> I'm able to manually add the necessary paths in the C/C++ build
> settings to get all of the includes resolved, but I was under the
> impression that importing an autotools project should automatically
> find these references. Am I incorrect in that assumption?

Your own experience tells you otherwise, notwithstanding your prior expectation.

In an Eclipse Autotools project, an Autotools build system is used to (configure and) build the project instead of any of Eclipse's built-in builders.  To the extent that there is a data flow between components, it is from Eclipse to the project, not the other way around.  The distributed Autotools artifacts (`Makefile.am`, `configure.ac`, *etc*.) are opaque to Eclipse, except inasmuch as it has content highlighting for those file types (IIRC).  Artifacts built by configuring the project are not only opaque, but also ignored by policy.

Comment: yes.  I have abandoned this idea for the reasons you mentioned and moved to manually entering the missing include paths using system variables and then exporting that to a file for the rest of the team to import.

I will note that using autotools, I was able to get eclipse to pick up most of the missing includes.  I had to set the --prefix value in eclipse, run Reconfigure Project, then Build Project, to get this to work, which is not what I was really looking/hoping for.  It also was not 100% correct this way, and as such, not a viable option.  Thanks!